# For webStorm or phpStorm, is there a way to automatically run Sync with remote server when opening a file?

Tags: ide, server, phpstorm, synchronization, webstorm

I'm new to using PHPStorm. I find myself overwriting stuff in the remote server because I forgot to sync and download the newest thing from the server.

My question is: is there a way to automatically run sync every time I open up a file? I figure this will solve my carelessness issue. Or if anyone has any better solution, feel free to list them.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should be able to configure IDE to notify before overwriting over newer file & at that point to can do a diff merge manually. Check your deployment Options: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/options.html?search=deployment

Comment: Options to look at: 1) `Warn when uploading over newer file` 2) `Notify about remote changes`